# Flat file source has float value as 10.65 but oledb destination (SQL server) is taking the value as 10.6499996185303

Tags: mysql, ssis

Flat file source has float value as 10.65 but oledb destination (SQL server) is taking the value as 10.6499996185303
Please help me to get value as 10.65 in MYSQL server

Comment: Welcome to the [wild world of floating point values](https://floating-point-gui.de). If you need precision, use a *fixed place* type.

Comment: is this really mysql?  or sql server?  they are very different things

Comment: if you want fixed values, use 'decimal'